# what are the minimum requirements for the camera to be UHS 1 compatible?

Tags: sdxc, specification

The [specification](http://www.engadget.com/2010/06/24/sd-cards-branded-with-an-upper-case-i-are-faster-yo/) fof uhs 1 says that those card are able to transfer data up to 104 MB/s
I was wondering if a camera that support it (the D7000 for example) should be able to transfert data at the maximum rate ?

Right now it does not seem like the D7000 does take [full advantage](http://www.photographybay.com/2011/01/27/sandisk-extreme-pro-uhs-i-sd-card-in-the-nikon-d7000/) of the increase in speed.

Comment: Erm... 1.9 frames per second * 35MB RAWs == 66.5MB/s -- almost 50% more than Sandisk specifies for the card. I don't think the camera is the bottleneck here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The D7000 is, I think, much like the Pentax K-5 in this regards (the reviewer is incorrect on his assertion about camera support). The camera is compatible with version 3 of the SD specification (SDXC) but that doesn't mean that the camera has the necessary hardware to take advantage of the greater transfer rates, though it can take advantage of some speed gains since SDHC cards don't usually hit the max for their specification. SDHC devices can handle SDXC given the right drivers and software, but that doesn't mean that they can take full advantage of the specs.

I think this, to some degree at least, bears out with the testing described in your links with some gain on the other card, but probably not enough for most shooters to spend the extra cash. Gotta love the transitional period, it leaves people unsure of what to buy.

Comment: that's what i was afraid of, it seems being able to write on a uhs1  card is enough to label your device as uhs1 compatible. So no luck on having noticeably better performance in burst shooting from the d7000